# Why in WSO2 ESB I can't create two different APIs having the same context value?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am not so into WSO2 ESB and I have the following problem.

Into my ESB project I have 2 different APIs that have **the same context** but handling different URLs.

1) The first one is named **CommoditiesInACountry** and it is defined in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/country" name="CommoditiesInACountry" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{localizationId}/commodities">
    ..............................................................
    ..............................................................
    ..............................................................
```

2) The second one is named **CommodityInLocationMarkets** and it is defined in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/country" name="CommodityInLocationMarkets" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{localizationId}/commodity/{commodityId}">
    ..............................................................
    ..............................................................
    ..............................................................
```

So as you can see both have the same context having the value **/country** but the 2 APIs handle different URLs, infact the first one handle the resource **.../country/{localizationId}/commodities** and the second one handle the resouce **.../country/{localizationId}/commodity/{commodityId}**

the problem is that when I deploy my Carbon application I obtain the following error message related to the fact that I have 2 differents APIs having the same context value:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-01 15:37:31,573]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} -  Initializing API: CommodityInLocationMarkets {org.apache.synapse.rest.API}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-01 15:37:31,573] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration} -  URL context: /country is already registered with the API: CommoditiesInACountry {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-01 15:37:31,573] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.ApiDeployer} -  API deployment from the file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed. {org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.ApiDeployer}
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: URL context: /country is already registered with the API: CommoditiesInACountry
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.handleException(SynapseConfiguration.java:1629)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.addAPI(SynapseConfiguration.java:407)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:59)
        at org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.ApiDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ApiDeployer.java:34)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:194)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:131)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-01 15:37:31,574] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} -  Deployment of the Synapse Artifact from file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed! {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer}
org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed.
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:474)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.ApiDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ApiDeployer.java:34)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:194)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:131)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: URL context: /country is already registered with the API: CommoditiesInACountry
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.handleException(SynapseConfiguration.java:1629)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.addAPI(SynapseConfiguration.java:407)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:59)
        ... 22 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-01 15:37:31,576]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} -  The file has been backed up into : NO_BACKUP_ON_WORKER.INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-01 15:37:31,576] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} -  Deployment of synapse artifact failed. Error reading /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : API deployment from the file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed. {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer}
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed.
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:201)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:131)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed.
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:474)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.ApiDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ApiDeployer.java:34)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:194)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: URL context: /country is already registered with the API: CommoditiesInACountry
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.handleException(SynapseConfiguration.java:1629)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.addAPI(SynapseConfiguration.java:407)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:59)
        ... 22 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-01 15:37:31,577] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Error occurred while deploying Carbon Application {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed.
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:213)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:131)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed.
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:201)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /opt/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1512139051333agrimarketprice-cap_1.0.0.car/CommodityInLocationMarkets_1.0.0/CommodityInLocationMarkets-1.0.0.xml : Failed.
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:474)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.ApiDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ApiDeployer.java:34)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:194)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: URL context: /country is already registered with the API: CommoditiesInACountry
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.handleException(SynapseConfiguration.java:1629)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.addAPI(SynapseConfiguration.java:407)
        at org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:59)
```

Changing one of the 2 APIs context value it is correctly deployed on my Carbon server.

My problem is that I need that the URL of both these 2 APIs start with **.../country** that is defined by the context value.

How is it possible that **WSO2 ESB** don't allow to have the same context for two APIs? How can I create two different APIs both having an URL like: **XXX.YYY.ZZZ.RRR/country/...**

Is it possible do in using **WSO2 ESB**?

A possible solution (correct me if it is wrong) maybe could be have two different contect of my APIs and then map it into **WSO2 API MANAGER** defining here the final URL consumed by the final user.

What could be a solution?

Comment: ESB/APIM don't allow creating 2 APIs with the same context. Is there any specific reason for the need of 2 APIs with the same context without having just one with multiple resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESB/APIM don't allow creating 2 APIs with the same context. But, you can use one API and have multiple resources like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/country" name="CommoditiesInACountry" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{localizationId}/commodities">
        ................................
        ................................
    </resource>
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{localizationId}/commodity/{commodityId}">
        ................................
        ................................
    </resource>
</api>
```

**On a related note:** To adhere to REST standards, your second resource should be `/{localizationId}/commodities/{commodityId}`